# PASSWORD() function no longer working after server move

Tags: mysql

I have moved my website and MySQL database to a new, free server at webhost.com, running MySQL 5.0.91-community.

Already, I have noticed that the MySQL server "does not like" the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users_tb WHERE user_name='student' and user_pass=PASSWORD("password_here").
```

I have tried it in PhpMyAdmin, where no results are returned. If I leave out the password clause and just search by username, it works.

This code worked on the previous server. What has changed?

Comment: password() is used for the mySQL user table; you really shouldn't use it in your own applications, as there's no contract as to its behavior (the offical docs recommend against using it in the fashion you have).

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. And what was the previous version? Hard to make a comparison without knowing that...

Comment: @Erik: Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @Tomalak: wasn't sure if I was correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PASSWORD` behaves differently depending on (1) the version of MySQL, and (2) whether or not the admin has activated `old-passwords` in my.ini.

Comment: Yes, and the OP should not have used it at all. Prefer `MD5`.

Comment: @Tomalak. MD5? That has been secure in ages. As Bruce Schneider said: "walk don't run to a more secure hash. Use SHA512 instead.

Comment: @Johan: Sure, "or some other MySQL-native hashing function". Prefer `SHA512` to `MD5`, but still prefer `MD5` to `PASSWORD`. :P

Comment: @Tomalak, @Johan: and prefer `BCRYPT` to `SHA512` as its a slow hashing function and with a proper work factor you can cause it to take .25sec PER HASH - trival during a log-in, but it makes cracking an 8 char password impossible for anything not in a 'common passwords' table.